# solana validator is running but catch command is not showing any thing

Tags: help

[image]We have followed all the step for sol setup from here https://www.cherryservers.com/blog/how-to-run-a-solana-node

From tail command we are seeing the log file screenshot has been attach.

But the catch up dont show us anything we need the help.[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `solana catchup` command will try to compare what your node is reporting against some RPC service. In your case, `solana catchup` is trying to compare your node's progress to mainnet-beta, since the error is coming from https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com

You haven't specified what network your node is running against, but if you've been following the provided doc, your node is talking to testnet. This means your catchup command should read:

```
solana --url testnet catchup <YOUR_PUBKEY>
```